# Blender doesn't start up

Tags: error, opengl

Good evening,

I've been having an issue where the program itself won't start up after the initial command prompt window has disappeared. The program fully closes, it doesn't show that it's not responding in the task manager or anything like that. It's weird, because i have used Blender without any issue fine last year on the same computer.

I have looked at many solutions other people came with, including updating Windows, multiple re-installs as well as emptying / deleting the contents in the Blender Foundation folder within Appdata/Roaming as well as Local. Have also tried older versions, one directly from a .zip, .msi's and using the one from Steam as well, but sadly still have the same issue.

When starting up from Steam, i'm given the 'Blender requires a graphics card that supports OpenGL 3.3 or higher' error. When i add an opengl32.dll to the directory (for non-steam) or rename it to opengl33.dll (since i've read that solved it for others), i get the "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION" error instead. My graphics card should be able to handle OpenGL 3.3 as the version on my PC is 4.6. All drivers are up-to-date. Errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJrge.jpg / https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptjt0.jpg

My PC specs are:
Geforce GTX 1060 6GB
Driver version 451.77
Intel Core i7-6700k CPU @ 4.000 GHz
Intel(R) HD Graphics 53015.88 GB RAM
Screen 1920 x 1080, 60 Hz

I have fully reset my PC as well in the hopes this would fix the issue, but the problem still remains. Does anyone maybe have experience with this issue or perhaps knows how to solve it? Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Have you already tried to update the driver for your integrated GPU (Intel HD Graphics 530), using the current drivers from Intel's website?

Comment: I have updated them again through Intel's website and it's Driver & Support Assistant, but sadly the result is still the same with the exception violation error. The current Intel driver version is 27.20.100.8336. If adding the opengl32.dll, the screen flashes as if something is opening but no actual window appears that stays. With this method no error or other message appears in the cmd either aside for a new line to put a command in.

Comment: Download Blender 2.90 from [here](https://builder.blender.org/download/), open Blender's installation directory and double click on the `blender_debug_gpu.cmd`. This will start Blender in debug mode and create log files. Try to make Blender crash again. Once it crashes the Windows Explorer should open and show you two files. Add them to your bug report by clicking on the upload button as shown in the screenshot below. Please also upload the crash log located in `C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Local\Temp\blender.crash.txt`.

Comment: Please create a [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/) using the instructions above.

Comment: I have followed the steps but the debug logs folder only showed 1 file. I assume i had to do it another time with the added opengl32.dll? The two debug output files and the crash report have been added to the bug report: https://developer.blender.org/T79229